# ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core) - unable to run with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET 5 MVC project to local IIS, but facing with some errors.

## Error

When open (my website address) `localhost:80` I've got HTTP 404. I facing the same behaviour if I manualy run the `approot\web.cmd`. I think the problem is same. In `web.cmd` console I see this output for every request (for non-static routes, static files works good):

```
fail: Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory[1]
  An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. File not found.
  File name: 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load the specified file.
  File name: 'System.Data.SqlClient'
     at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyName)
     at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Resolve(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
     at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
     at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
     at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
     at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
     at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
```

### Problem

When I run the **`dnx web`** from my project development directory `MySolution\src\MyProject` **It's all OK**

## My Project.json

You can see that I am using `dnxcore50` and haven't dependency to `System.Data.SqlClient`.

```
{
"userSecretsId": "aspnet5-Stomatology-b7dc4859-6376-4a5f-a583-d17b3660a64c",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
},

"dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "4.1.1",
    "Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
},

"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},

"frameworks": {
"dnxcore50": { }
},

"exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
],
"publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
],
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install" ]
}
```

}

## My deploying and IIS settings

1. I deploy using `File System` options, like in manauls
2. I installed HTTP Platform Handler
3. I used Application Pool without managment environment

## Conclusion

So, is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: dnx don't copy all the referenced dll's, copy that dll from our framework to the deployed bin folder.

Comment: @Gusman, I'll try it. But why I need `System.Data.Entity` if I use `EF7`, which has no dependencies to `System.Data*`, but has dependencies to `Microsoft.Data.*`?

Comment: P.S. `bin` you mean `myapp\approot\runtimes\myruntime\bin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it works. Below are the steps I have taken to get it to work:

1. **The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**

   - Install HTTP Platform Handler
   - Make sure that ASP.NET 4.6 enabled in Windows Components: Internet  Information Servies ->World Wide Services -> Application Development Components -> ASP.NET 4.6
2. **Unable to load `System.Data.SqlClient`**

   - Add `System.Data.SqlClient` to your `project.json`
3. **Unable to load `sni.dll`**

   - Use x64 coreclr runtime on x64 OS.
   - Install MS VC++ 2012 redistributable

If It still doesnt't work... *(help for me for present day 08.02.2016 with 1.0.0-rc1-update1)*:
 - remove all dnx runtimes
 - install latest Update for ASP.NET and Web tools in Visual Studio 
 - set the latest x64 runtime in VS in deploy settings

I think, this is a some kind of magic, I don't know, why this works.

Comment: any chance you can replace screenshot with the English one? if not - please remove it.